# how to reduce number of transactions while fetching multiple fields using JPA query has has multiple conditions in where clause

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a function in my code that connects to postgress db using spring jpa. It fetches the execution count and workflow id of all the workflows in a table  using the following query.

```
select execution_count, workflow_id from <table> where version =<> and run_id =<>
```

The version and run_id here are not the keys.(so I cannot using findAllById)
I'am re-writing this  function to a do a bulk fetch.
I can use a for loop following way

```
for(...) { int count = runDetailsDao.getExecutionCount(version,run_id)
```

However each time the loop iterates a new transaction is created, which doesn't seem an efficient way if the loop iterates too many times (say 200).how can I reduce the number of transactions. What would be an efficient way in this case?

Comment: Start a transaction outside the for loop and you have a single one. If you get a tx per method call it means the method itself isn't transactional, which probably should be.  None the less doing N queries to retrieve N results isn't the smartest, why not write a single query that returns everything in one go?

Comment: @M.Deinum . If I have to write something like  
`select execution_count, workflow_id from <table> where version in (<....>) and run_id  in (<...>)`
and lets say I pass in workflowId=('w1','w2','w3') and version=('v1','v2','v3').
The output i need is w1 and v 2 , w2 and v1 and w3 and v3 however it would return me w1 1 , w2 2 , w3 3 and w2 1 , w3 2 and all the combinations  where a match is found.

Comment: You can use in with tuples... `where (version, run_id) in ( ('v1', 'w1), ('v2', 'w1'), ......)`....